# Is it legal create an algorithmic trading cryptocurrency fund for social groups around the globe to pool in their money?

Tags: tokens, ether, bitcoin

Is it legal create an algorithmic trading cryptocurrency fund for social groups around the globe to pool in their money? What is the viability of this project in terms of regulatory compliance?

Comment: That'd count as money laundering. You'll most likely have to do "Know Your Customer".

Comment: Thanks for this. Provided that KYC and AML processes are in place, are there any other regulatory issues to consider generally speaking for this to work?

Comment: I can't say anything other than that because IANAL and it depends on the country you're living. I suggest you to ask this question at https://law.stackexchange.com/